# Adding an additional condition to a MS SQL query

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to add another check to the query below, so if user is in zone 100 it wont allow him to transfer. Column in database is `Zone`, so how to add correctly a check to see if user is in `Zone 100` to wont allow him to transfer.

```
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, TransferTime FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = ? AND (TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL)', $character);

if ($num_rows == -1) {
    $db->GetError(__file__, __line__);
    $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('DB_ERROR');
    return false;
} else if ($num_rows == 0) {
    $this->m_ccError = Template::GetLangVar('RECENT_TRANSFER');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to add this logic yourself?

Comment: Yeah but thought of asking better since i dont want to break something

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I edited it like that now: `SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, Zone, TransferTime 
FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = ? AND 
(TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL) and Zone<>100` and it works now. Is that correct? I've added Zone at select as well .. let me know if this query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the query below:

```
SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, TransferTime 
FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = ? AND 
(TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL and Zone<>100
```

I've just added "Zone<>100" in the query to exclude the users where Zone is 100.

Comment: This wont allow him to transfer if he is at zone 100 right? Or as I see it will allow only those players that are in this zone ?

Comment: I added it and people still can change the class even that they are in zone 100

Comment: You have to add the above mentioned condition in the query where you are fetching the list of users who are trying to transfer.

Comment: I've added it `AND zone<>100` and when i execute it via MSSQL with character id that is in that zone, it doesnt show any row but on the php it works and they can change class. I believe it should error when it see that the player is in `Zone 100`

Comment: I edited it like that and it works now: `SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, Zone, TransferTime 
FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = ? AND 
(TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL) and Zone<>100` let me know if this query is correct now ?

Comment: I think the query is fine now.

Comment: Actually I removed Zone from SELECT and left and zone<>100 but not between () like you did ... you pasted it in TransferTime check and now when it's outside of it .. it works. Was your correct to be in () or now it should be correct outside of it ?

Comment: Basically that: `(TransferTime < DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL and Zone<>100` you see `)` is missing in your query but I added it like it was at `NULL) and Zone<>100` and now it works. So I asked if your was correct or mine now with `)`

Comment: Oh I got it. Yes, you are correct , Zone<>100 needs to be added outside those brackets.

Comment: I even added another check to see if the user is banned `255` it wont allow him too. Please confirm that the query below is correct now:
`SELECT Class, Race, Strong, Sta, Dex, Intel, Cha, Points, TransferTime FROM USERDATA WHERE strUserId = ? AND (TransferTime < DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,GETDATE()) OR TransferTime IS NULL) and zone<>100 and authority<>255`

Comment: I mean is it correct and nobody can exploit it after adding these checks `<>` ??? Please let me know that and I'll mark it as you solved my problem.

Comment: Your query looks good, but you have to verify the conditions yourself and make sure it is fulfilling all the criteria

Comment: I checked and it worked. But I was asking if this query after adding `<>` could be exploited ?

Comment: What kind of "exploited" are you talking about?  You should add many more details.